# I want to get time from time picker when certain text is tapped in android

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I am trying to build an app in which I have to get the app running for a specified period of time. I want to use time picker for this. I have two text views 'From' and 'Two' as labels which translates to starting and ending time and other two text views for displaying the selected time.

So, I want the text picker to to be activated when either 'From' or 'To' text is tapped and show the time picked from time picker into the text views corresponding to them.

What methods should I use or what interfaces should I implement?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: I tried something, but the code was too messy to publish. Anyway, I used TimePickerDialog as it is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android Developer API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) explains how to use Pickers well, and shows simple example code.